# TableView is blinking while reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, infinite-scroll

I am implementing infinite scroll in iOS app (when user scrolls to the bottom - new API call is used to get more values and show them as tableview cells).

I run this function when user is near last shown cell

```
 func loadItems() {

    isFetchingMore = true

    //reloading section 1 with loading indicator
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .none)

    let url = URL(string: someURL)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        let newItems = (self.items.count...self.items.count+10).map {
            index in
            Item(display_name: "item \(index)", location: "subitem \(index)")
        }
        self.items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
        self.isFetchingMore = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

As you see - new items are added for test purpose with map function. In this case everything is working as it expected. But when I replace this mocks

```
        let newItems = (self.items.count...self.items.count+10).map {
            index in
            Item(display_name: "item \(index)", location: "subitem \(index)")
        }
```

with code that gets data from JSON

```
if let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String : Any] {
                if let jsonItems = json["items"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                    for item in jsonItems {
                        if let display_name = item["display_name"] as? String,
                            let location = item["location"] as? String {
                            newItems.append(Item(display_name: display_name, location: location))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

TableView starts to blink on updates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your updates are probably too fast.

Comment: Don't use `reloadData`. Use `insertRows` to add new rows to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 10, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 11, section: 0)], with: .none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Note that you'll have to iterate over the existing visible cells and create the array as the first argument of the method in 3 line of code.

Answer (score 0):

try updating properties of cells that change instead of reloading whole the tableView.